# store logged in user details in xamarin forms using SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin forms applicaiton which will have three welcome pages while the user is logging into the applicaiton for the first time, if the user user is trying to start the application after logging in only dashboard has to be displayed. I have written the following code for that :

```
  public LoginUserInfoDbModel SaveUserDetails(LoginUserInfoDbModel model)
        {
            if(model.LoggedInUser!=null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                connection.Insert(model);
                return model;
            }
        }
```

and called the above method in LoginPage.xaml.cs in the following way :

```
if (model.ResultString == "Valid")
                {

                    App.UserDatabase.SaveUserDetails(model);

                    await DisplayAlert("", "You have logged in succesfully ", "Ok");
                     await Navigation.PushAsync(new DashBoardPage());
                }
```

So now I need to check whether the User is already a existing user or not in DB, so I have written the following code in App.xaml.cs :

```
 var connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>().GetConnection();
    var c=connection.CreateTableAsync<LoginUserInfoDbModel>().Result;
    var UserData =  connection.Table<LoginUserInfoDbModel().ToListAsync().Result?.FirstOrDefault();
 if(UserData != null)
{
MainPage= new DashBoardPage();
}
else
{
MainPage=new WelcomePages();
}
```

But this code is not working I am getting null reference Exception and some other exceptions, So do we have any alternative for this scenario or else can you suggest any modifications for this code ?

Comment: "null reference Exception and some other exceptions" - this is not helpful.  Which SPECIFIC line is causing the null ref, and which SPECIFIC "other" exceptions are you getting?

Comment: I am getting the exception while getting the connection itself                      var connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>().GetConnection();

Comment: then there is probably something wrong with your implementation of ISQLiteDb